# Second Moment Method Proof

Tags: inequality, random-variables, random

I'm proving the Second Moment Method. I'm aware of the stronger solution. But I'm trying to figure out a detail in the "weak" version. We need to prove that
$$P(X=0) \leq \frac{Var(X)}{(E[X])^{2}} = \frac{E[X]^{2}}{(E[X])^{2}} - 1.$$

The first step is of course to use the Chebychev's inequality, which gives us

$$P(|X - E[X]| \geq E[X]) \leq \frac{Var(X)}{(E[X])^{2}} = \frac{E[X]^{2}}{(E[X])^{2}} - 1.$$
My question is now, how do we get that $P(X = 0) \leq P(|X - E[X]| \geq E[X])$? Can someone give an intuitive explanation on how we get here. If feel like it makes sense, but I'm just not satisfied with "feeling" good about it just being true. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you at least need an assumption that $E[X] \ge 0$.

If $X=0$ then $|X-E[X]| =|E[X]| = E[X]$, so $\{X = 0\} \subseteq \{|X-E[X]| \ge E[X]\}$.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention that $X$ is a none-negative integer valued random variable. Thus, $E[X] \geq 0$. Thank you for your answer. My intuition was something similar to your answer, namely that $\{X = 0\} \subseteq \{X \geq 0\}$, but my problem was where $\{|X-E[X]| \geq E[X]\}$ would be placed.